# How does this recursive construction of a class work?

Tags: c#, constructor

I am reading "C# in a Nutshell" and there is this snippet of code that I can not wrap my head around:

```
class Foo 
{
    public static Foo Instance = new Foo();
    public static int X = 3;
    Foo() {
       Console.WriteLine(X);
    } 
}


class Program
{
  static void Main() { 
      Console.WriteLine(Foo.X); 
      Foo myfoo = new Foo();
      Console.WriteLine(Foo.X);
  }
}
```

Question: What steps will happen when we call the constructor "Foo myfoo = new Foo()"? Is not this program doomed?

Comment: Doomed in what sense? Construction of an instance != class initialization.

Comment: Where do you see recursion?

Comment: The constructor is private, so the `myFoo = new Foo()` will not compile.

Comment: I´d rather add `readonly` to the field: `public static readonly Foo Instance = new Foo();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no recursion at all. In fact, it's a well known pattern called "[singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)".

Actually, **the code won't even compile**. The constructor is private (the default [access modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) is `private`), so the only possible way to create an instance of `Foo` is to be inside the `Foo` class itself, which is done by:

```
public static Foo Instance = new Foo();
```

So basically this code exposes a `public static` instance of `Foo`, and you can't construct any other instance because you can't call the constructor from outside the `Foo` class itself.

Comment: You mean that actually the line "Instance = new Foo();" is executed only ONCE in the whole program? Because it is a static field, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Foo Instance = new Foo();
```

The [static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) keyword means that it belongs to the type rather than to the object.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a singleton, the static Foo instance "Instance" will be the same to all project, so its not "recursive", if it wasn't static, yeah, you would be in troubles because of allocating infinite instances of "Foo" eating all your ram, but since there is only one instance being shared,there is no problem with the code

Comment: It would eat the stack, no extra ram, leading to a StackOverflowException. But c# prevents that anyway, you won't be able to compile self-recursion in constructors.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you have provided shows in your main that you are printing the `X` variable from the `Foo` Class three times.

The second Line you have created an **instance** of `foo` although you have not used it anywhere else.

Note your third line is `Console.WriteLine(Foo.X);`
If you wanted to use the result received from the constructor (Which would have been initialised during the creation of the foo object *(line 2)* then you would have to use the line `Console.WriteLine(Myfoo.X)`

I would expect the output of your application to be:

```
3
3
3
```

Comment: I think the output will be 0;3;3;3, because the first instance (the static one) will be created before the static int value is assigned...

Answer (score 0):

For a start this won't compile because the constructor is not public.

Secondly no it's not doomed, it just means that there will be two instances of Foo constructed.

The first instance is when the static reference to Foo is created. This will call the constructor and output 0 as the code hasn't got to the point of initializing the static variable X.

The constructor will again get called to construct the second instance of Foo but this time the static variable will be set to 3 so the console ouput would be 3.

That's it.

As others have noted the constructor is made private to enforce the singleton pattern. So the access to the instance should be through the static class variable.

```
Foo foo = Foo.Instance;
```

The problem with this is that the static variable X will be 0 when it is output to the console because the construction of the instance is before the initialization of X.